# JS Countdown Code

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Ive searched a lot of places and most of the places  ive seen only have code for countdown to a day. I was wondering if anyone would do me a solid and write, yes, write some JS for the following HTML to work.

This is a website I created for my team at work. This part of the website will help keep their time when the take certain breaks or put a customer on hold or when their trying to notate an account.

```
    <html>
    <FORM name="sw">
    <TABLE border="0" width="30px">
    <TR><TH colspan="4">Timers</TH></TR>


    <TR align="center">

    <TD><b>Lunch</b></TD>
     <TD><input type="text" name="beg2" size="7" value="60:00"></TD>
    <TD><input type="button" value="Start" onclick="Down()"></TD>
    <td><input type="text" name="disp2" size="9"></TD>
     <TD><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetTimer()"></td>

   </TR>

   <TR align="center">

      <TD><b>Breaks</b></TD>
   <TD><input type="text" name="beg2" size="7" value="15:00"></TD>
   <TD><input type="button" value="Start" onclick="Down()"></TD>
   <td><input type="text" name="disp2" size="9"></TD>
   <TD><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetTimer()"></td>

  </TR>

   <TR align="center">

  <TD><b>Wrap</b></TD>
   <TD><input type="text" name="beg2" size="7" value="00:30"></TD>
    <TD><input type="button" value="Start" onclick="Down()"></TD>
  <td><input type="text" name="disp2" size="9"></TD>
     <TD><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetTimer()"></td>

    </TR>
   <TR align="center">

  <TD><b>Hold</b></TD>
   <TD><input type="text" name="beg2" size="7" value="02:00"></TD>
      <TD><input type="button" value="Start" onclick="Down()"></TD>
    <td><input type="text" name="disp2" size="9"></TD>
  <TD><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetTimer()"></td>

  </TR>

     </TABLE>
    </FORM>
  </html>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dCUm7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

http://jsbin.com/IFifEli/3/

There are lots of improvements to be done!

Comment: thank you, I just got to get to show in minutes rather than just seconds, but thank you again!